# Skipping JSON output in a loop

Tags: python, json, steam-web-api

I'm using Python to extract data using Steam's API.  I have a randomly generated list of Steam ID's.  The problem is, not all of these ID's point to valid accounts.  When I try to access the account for which there is no object value, the program gives me a "KeyError".  The Steam API will output a ['response'] level object for any requests, so when i print using that topmost level, I will get a response for every request.  However, if I go one more level in (e.g. ['response']['game_count']), the program will fail when it gets to an account which does not have any ['game_count'] value.  How do I tell python to just skip these accounts?

Example output:

account with game (Removed extra returns for readability)

```
{
"response": {
    "game_count": 1,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 205790,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

account without game

```
{
    "response": {
    }
}
```

My current code:

```
import urllib2, random, sys, json

list = open('d:\python\SteamUserIDs.txt').read().splitlines()
SteamID = str(list)


for SteamID in list[0:10:1]:
    request = urllib2.Request('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=05475AE5A8410CE01236A8A29E1DEE8E&steamid=%s&format=json' %SteamID, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"})
    response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
    request2 = urllib2.Request('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0001/?key=05475AE5A8410CE01236A8A29E1DEE8E&steamids=%s&format=json' %SteamID, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"})
    response2 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options.

- The first option is [in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) or `not in`. An important note about this one, if you see recommendations to use `has_key()`, don't. It has been deprecated in Python 2.x and removed in Python 3.x. Instead, you use the `in` operator.

> Return True if d has a key key, else False.

```
if 'game_count' in response:
    # Do something
```

Or, the `not` version:

```
if 'game_count' not in response:
    # skip/pass on this record
else:
    # Do something
```

- The next option, like mentioned in another answer, is the [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

```
if response.get('game_count', None):
    # Do something
else:
    # skip/pass on this record
```

**Update**: You are not doing anything with your responses. That's why it looks like nothing is happening.

There are also a few things about your code that needs to be fixed:

- You are making unneeded calls to the API. You can pass up to 100 SteamIDs per call to the `GetPlayerSummaries`. You don't need to call it one at a time for each ID.
- Don't name your variable `list`
- `SteamID = str(list)` is pointless, as you are reusing the `SteamID` variable in your loop

This is a slightly modified version of your code

```
steam_ids = open('d:\python\SteamUserIDs.txt').read().splitlines()
steam_str = ','.join(steam_ids)    # This make a comma separated string that we will use in our API calls 

owned_games = {}

for s in steam_ids:
    request = urllib2.Request('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=<<YOURKEY>>&steamid=%s&format=json' % s,headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"})
    response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))['response']
    if response.get('game_count', None):
        owned_games[s] = response['game_count']
    else:
        owned_games[s] = None

# This call will only work if you have less than 100 steam ids. If you have more, you
# will need to build steam_str differently for batches of 100
request2 = urllib2.Request('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0001/?key=<<YOURKEY>>&steamids=%s&format=json' %steam_str, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"})
response2 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request2))
```

At the end of this, you will end up with a `owned_games` dictionary that looks like this (Profile IDs aren't accurate in this example).

```
{'76561197992702437': 63,
 '76561197992702438': 0,
 '76561197992702439': 0,
 '76561197995066524': 62,
 '76561197995066525': 0,
 '76561197995066526': 0,
 '76561197995066527': 0}
```

This dictionary is showing you how many games each profile owns. Then, in your `response2` object, you can parse through each item in `response2['response']['players']` to do your comparisons. Alternatively, you can rebuild the `players` list into a dictionary (or combine it with `games_owned` so that you don't need to loop through the list each time to find the appropriate profile. Either of these two exercises is beyond the scope of your initial question though.

Now, you will need to look at the data in `response` and `response2` for your parsing.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried these methods and they return no errors, the program seems to complete... but nothing happens.  I tried simply printing with "print response['response']['game_count']" and nothing happened.

Comment: @user3476845, I've updated my response to provide you with more details and help with your code

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the detailed response.  I actually have the code set up that way because of what I need to eventually do with one of the json objects.  I'm not only interested in the amount of games people own, but also various social variables (This is a psychological/statistics study).  For example, I want to roll up the "profileurl" json object into a variable so i can use that string to get more information about a player (Things that are not available in the API, such as the amount of games they review).

Comment: I tried using your code example and I'm still getting the "KeyError: 'game_count'" response.

Comment: @user3476845 check the update. It adds the `if response.get('game_count', None):` check to see if the key exists

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to work.  It's not the format I was expecting, but perhaps I should work off of this instead of what I was originally planning/expecting.  I'm somewhat confused as to why the if/else statement wasn't working with my original code, though.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  The current program outputs "None" for all steam users regardless of whether or not they own games.

Comment: @user3476845 Look at the update I made. I had the response incorrect. It was failing to check the proper json node.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

You are getting a key error because the key `game_count` doesn't exist. Check for that key before doing something (such as printing)

```
for response in steam_id_responses:
    if response.get('game_count', None):
        print response
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure how to implement the code you're providing.  I tried it multiple ways and all failed.  I will update my post with my current code if that helps.